# Dataframe in pandas brings row number along with property value when assigned to dictionary through a variable

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, key

I am creating a dictionary from a series of variables stored in .csv files, all of them are of the form:

```
Depth Leakoff
5500  2599.492
5501  2599.492
5502  2604.306549
```

I am using the following code to load the .csv files and assign to variables, later on, those variables are assigned to specific keys within the dictionary:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import Series, DataFrame

    Leakoff = pd.read_csv("Input/leakoff_file.csv")
    Leakoff = Leakoff.drop(FT.index[[0]]) #to drop the first row of data, it contains the physical units which I don't need

    Leakoff_md = FT["Depth"] #Input vector of depth
    Leakoff_val = FT["Leakoff"] #Input vector of some property called leakoff
    #Below is a fragment of the dictionary I need to create:

    project = {
        'name': 'Test_1',
        'info': 'Info linea 1\nInfo linea 2\nInfo linea 3\n',
        'version': '1.3.2',
        'data_version': 1,
        'leakoff': {
            'depth': (Leakoff_md, 'ft'),
            'leakoff': (Leakoff_val, 'ft/min^0.5')}
    }

print project #the dictionary with the updated values based on the variables loaded
```

I expected the result to be similar to this (the dictionary is very long, I'm just showing few lines...

```
project = {'microseismic': {'north': [], 'event_set': [], 'depth': [], 'magnitude': [], 'time': [], 'east': []}, 'reservoir': {'leakoff': {'leakoff': (2599.492, 2599.492, 2604.306549, 2604.306549, 2449.639619, 2449.639619, 2763.019369...
```

Instead this is what I'm getting:

```
{'microseismic': {'north': [], 'event_set': [], 'depth': [], 'magnitude': [], 'time': [], 'east': []}, 'reservoir': {'leakoff': {'leakoff': (1         2599.492
2         2599.492
3      2604.306549
4      2604.306549
5      2449.639619
6      2449.639619
7      2763.019369
```

How can I avoid the row numbers to be added to the variable when preparing the dictionary?

Thanks in advance for your help and comments!

Pegaso

Answer (score 1):

If select column of `DataFrame` by `[]` get `Series`.

```
Leakoff_md = FT["Depth"]
print (Leakoff_md)
0    5500
1    5501
2    5502
Name: Depth, dtype: int64

print (type(Leakoff_md))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

This numbers are `index` of `Series`, because appending `Series` to `dict`.

```
print (Leakoff_md.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)

print (Leakoff_md.index.tolist())
[0, 1, 2]
```

Solution is convert `Series` to `list`s:

```
Leakoff_md = FT["Depth"].tolist()
Leakoff_val = FT["Leakoff"].tolist()
```

A bit faster:

```
Leakoff_md = FT["Depth"].values.tolist()
Leakoff_val = FT["Leakoff"].values.tolist()

print (Leakoff_md)
[5500, 5501, 5502]
```

Comment: Jezrael, I used the command asking for the values:  Leakoff_md = Leakoff["MD"].values.tolist(), but still I have a problem, the dictionary comes as expected, but the values assigned from the variables came within single quotes: '252.25', '225.87', it looks like they are considered strings instead of numbers (float type), how can I fix this? Thanks again!

Comment: sure, need `FT["Depth"].astype(float).tolist()`

Comment: If not working because some bad data - text with numeric - `pd.to_numeric(FT["Depth"], errors='coerce').dropna().tolist()` ->it replace text to `NaN`s and `dropna` remove `NaN`s.